Problem with sample curve points and animating to a random position sequentially
I have this node setup:

The problem I'm facing, the first points on the curve are already moved away from the curve:

I want all the points to be at their origins (placed on the curve). Then I want to animate them sequentially from first to last.
I played with all sorts of values in the map range node, I can get it almost correct, but then it lacks in smoothness when animating the factor value of the sample curve: the points snaps to their final positions (displaced by the noise texture) instead of interpolating smoothly.

I found the solution. Instead of sampling the position of the points and subtracting them from the position, I'm using the indexes to get their position and playing with the indexes to map the factor of the mix vector. Not sure this is clear, but check out the node setup, it works for me.


